# Convert String to Plain Object

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have value as below which returned from a php request, so it is a string. How do I (convert to plain object) put it into data below?

```
"fieldName: \"ABC\", skill: \"1002\""

jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: setting_url,
                data: {},
                success: function (result) {},
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { },
                complete: function () { }
            });
```

Comment: Which data and what string?

Comment: What does the response look like? JSON?

Comment: the data is in jQuery.ajax and string is "fieldName: \"ABC\", skill: \"1002\""

Comment: nope, pure string as "fieldName: \"ABC\", skill: \"1002\""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var response = "\"fieldName\":\"ABC\",\"skill\":\"1002\""; // should look like
var obj = JSON.parse("{"+response+"}");

alert( obj )         // [object Object]
alert( obj.skill );  // 1002
```

Which means to have a valid string to be parsed into object, your **property key** should be wrapped into **double quotes**.

Comment: It sure is a pain to need the double quotes :(

Comment: @GôTô you can do it this way: `'"fieldName":"ABC","skill":"1002"'`

Comment: yes this is correct, but painful to write. I mean for a single line it's ok, but when you have a lot to write (for example when you use localize https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize) it is really a waste of time. I mean, when writing a plain object you simply put { fieldName: "ABC", skill: "1002" }